# How to implement Google App Engine authentication?

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, authentication

I would like my iPhone app to store & get data from my App Engine application, but how can I make sure only my app makes these requests?

Do I have to make a gmail account, and let that account login as administrator to my Google App Engine application? So I can use that account from within my iPhone app to handle the request?

I just don't want non iPhone app users to access the app engine application.
Any idea's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own API, and use whatever authentication method you prefer. You'll need to embed some sort of secret in your app that you use to authenticate with - for example, a randomly generated secret key.

In general, it's not possible to embed a key in user software that users can't extract. You have a slight advantage on the iPhone, because it's a very controlled platform: Most users have no way of accessing your app's binaries. You're still vulnerable to a user with a rooted iPhone disassembling your app and retrieving the secret, however - and there's nothing you can do about that.

Alternately, you can require users of your app to sign up for an account with your app, and authenticate users individually.